# How to remove topside unwanted space from QLPreviewController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am trying to change `UINavigationBar` background and tint color for `QLPreviewController`. Here, If I use below code I can able to change colors but getting unwanted spaces between preview file and navigation bar. How to fix this?

My code Below :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).tintColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(color:  colorLiteral(red: 0.9003542662, green: 0.4175613821, blue: 0.1471666098, alpha: 1)), for: .default)
present(quickLookController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: outputImage]

Comment: @vadian could you please provide some solution for this?

Comment: @PGDev please check this